Confusion about differential forms and integration
I'm self-studying general relativity using Sean M. Carroll's textbook. I recently made it to sections 2.9 and 2.10, which talk about differential forms and integration of functions on manifolds. I have a few questions about these notions, as Carroll doesn't spend too long introducing them.
Carroll defines the wedge product $A\wedge B$ as $(A\wedge B)_{\mu_1...\mu_{p+q}}=\frac{(p+q)!}{p!q!}A_{[\mu_1...\mu_p}B_{\mu_{p+1}...\mu_{p+q}]}$. So it is the totally antisymmetric product of $A$ and $B$. We are now supposed to interpret the volume element in an integral, $d^nx$, as $d^nx=\text{d}x^0\wedge...\wedge\text{d}x^{n-1}$, where $\text{d}x^i$ is the exterior derivative of $x^i$ and a basis one-form.
My question is that basis one-forms don't necessarily have infinitesimal length, so how are we to interpret this product as an infinitesimal volume element to be integrated? When the one-form $\text{d}x^i$ is introduced in Carroll's text, it is made clear that this is a unit one-form. Should it not have unit length, rather than infinitesimal length?
Please let me know if my questions need clarification. I am having some challenges expressing my own confusion here.

In $\int_a^bf(x),dx$ how do we interpret $dx$ as an infinitesimal line element? (Rhetoric question. I do not want to start that discussion again.) The most pedagogical material of a very helpful member in this forum is probably Ted Shifrin's lectures that are linked in his profile.

@KurtG., I see you are back at it again.

@MikhailKatz indeed I am. The second question about $\Delta x$ and $dx$ today. :)

@KurtG., Ah, I missed the first one.  Where is it?

Looking forward.

Regarding (in your last edit) why $dx^i$ is a unit one-form and at the same time a differential that we believed since the days of Leibniz having infinitesimal (hence zero) length. You have to understand that before Cartan $dx^i$ did not really have any meaning. It was just a symbol to tell us w.r.t. which variable we integrate. Cartan took that as an advantage to give a new algebraic structure to $dx^i$ and introduced their wedge products. This structure is very convenient when, for example, we change coordinates (do "pullbacks") etc.

I stop lecturing here. Others do that much better. Dive into the literature that was recommended.

When I was an undergraduate, I was initially confused about differential forms as they seemed too formal.  Then a friendly postdoc explained to me that to understand what is going on intuitively, just think of $dx\wedge dy$ as representing an infinitesimal area, and integration of a function against it as being summation of such areas weighted by the function.  This made things much clearer.  Not to imply that there exist actual infinitesimals (perish the thought).
In my classnotes here there are some intuitive explanations.

Read $dx^k$ as a difference of of the linear function $\mathbf x \mapsto x^1$ of the first entry in the cartesian coordinate map from points to vectors from origin to points to number lists: $\mathbf P \mapsto  \mathbf x\mapsto \left(x^1,\dots,x^n\right)$ in a fixed coordinate system. It's the projection of the tangent vector $\mathbf v= \sum_k v^k \mathbf e_i$ in flat space $\mathbb R^n$ without any metrics, just plain cartesian maps in  $\mathbb R^n$.
Then in  $\mathbb R^n$ there is the chain of flat k-volumes of parallel epipeds.
Starting with
$$\text{length:} \ \int_a^b dx^1 = x^1(b)-x^1(a):= \int_a^b x^1 $$
$$ \text{area:} \ \int_{(a,b)\times(c,d)} \ dx^1\wedge dx^2 = \text{signature}\left((a,b,c,d)\right)\  \int_{(a,b)} dx^1 \  \int_{(c,d)} dx^2$$
with signature defined positive if the points follow counterclockwise on the closed contour.
$$\mathbb \vdots$$
$$\int\dots \dots$$
$$\mathbb \vdots$$
and finally the $n$-volume form
$$\int_{\large{\mathbf \times}_{i=1}^n{(a_i,b_i)}} dx^1\wedge \dots \wedge dx^n=\text{orientation}\left({\large{\mathbf \times}_{i=1}^n{(a_i,b_i)}}\right)\ \prod_i\int_{a_i}^{b_i}$$
With some rules of coordinate transforms one gets
$$\int_{\mathbf x \in V}  dx^a \wedge \dots \wedge dx^b = \int_{\mathbf y \in f(V)} \text{pfaffian}\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\right)\left(a,\dots b\right) dy^1 \wedge \dots \wedge dy^n $$
Where the pfaffian is the antisymmetric product of partial derivatives as far as x^{a\dots b} involves  with orientation factor produced by the signature of the wedge product wrt to a standard oriented series in $1,\dots n$.
So, in curvilinear coordinates in flat $\mathbb R^n$ the volume k forms do not factor anymore in a product of linear integrals to express all oriented $k$-volumes in the $n$ dimensional exterior algebra of $\mathbb R^n$, and the curvilinear 1-forms have to be interpreted as local linear maps from the local tangent bundle to the number field
$$dy^k(\mathbf e_l) = \delta_m^k,\quad dy^k(\sum_l \frac{ d x^l(t)}{dt}\ \mathbf  e_l) = \dot x^k(t)$$
$$\int_{\mathit C} dy^k = \int_0^1  dy^k\left( \dot{\mathbf x}(t) \right) dt$ = \int_0^1    \dot  x^k(t) ) dt$$
After having established the $m$-form integral calculus for flat epipeds of any dimension, that enables Stokes theorem for partitions by automatic cancellation of all inner surface integrals, on may leave the flat world and expand the integration to the Lebesgue-Stieljes integral with any n-form, that evaluates to any form of tensor fields on manifolds.
After this notational introduction via forms as families of coordinate projections in any oblique cartesian coordinate system by counting the number of hyperplanes passed by a vector, the introduction of a metric demands a special course, because the conventional representations of tensor analysis either specialize on electrodynamics in a fixed $\mathbb R^3$ frame or on Ricci calculus of components that is commutative, but is poor in orientation tracking.
The 3-d picture of flat forms is identical of the system of vectors at points with families of parallel planes as projectors.

